# Adjust altitude of points in kml to ground level

Tags: google-earth-pro

I have recorded a path using GPS and imported the kml file into google earth.
Due to inaccuracies in recording the path (I assume) the points are sometimes above or below the ground.
Is there a way to adjust the altitude of the points to ground level?
In the path properties, I see the option to "Extend to ground", but this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without modifying your GPS data, your best solution is to modify the altitude in GE to "Clamped to ground" as shown in the image below (right-click on a layer in GE and go to properties, look under the Altitude tab).  Perhaps this is what you mean by "Extend to ground".  However, without modifying your GPS data itself, this will probably be your only solution.

[image]

Comment: What about the web app version of Google Earth?  It does not seem to have anything equivalent.